# Angular project compile additional .js file from .ts in project output folder

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

In the angular project I need to compile separate "script.js", which is included in index.html.
This file is needs to be compiled from many *.ts files, which are imported to one main file "script.ts". 
I need to place this output script.js in the folder, where are placed other compiled files main.js, styles.js etc. And I need recompile "script.js" along with Angular project when I do save.

I tried to add some settings to tsconfig.json and angular.json, but I couldn't understand how to change them to get what I need.

Comment: Here are the things you may want to know about production - https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Did you manage to do that? I have a single `env.js` file which gets its contents replaced by our CI/CD, and I want to use typescript in there in development stages, (`env.ts`) and have it compile down to `env.js` as a separate output file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are searching for the `--outFile` compiler option in tsconfig which concatenates the result of transpiling your *.ts files.